# Packer and post installation script

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, packer

I've started using Packer and I have a question. Is there any solution to add a script which will be started automatically and only once after an Ubuntu VM will be deployed from a managed image on Azure?

I was able to do the same in AWS by adding the script to `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-instance` but what should I be doing in case of Azure?

Comment: Is the custom script extension what you look for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-scripts-in-vm?

Comment: No, not an extension

Comment: I am looking for a directory in Ubuntu VM where I can add my script while creating a managed image using packer and when I launch a VM using the image the script runs automatically

Comment: If you need to inject a script or other metadata into a Microsoft Azure virtual machine at provisioning time, Have a look at [Custom data and Cloud-Init on Azure Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-data)?

Comment: This is the case when I add a script while creating a VM through azure CLI. What I need is to get already uploaded script running as soon as the VM is launched

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any solution to add a script which will be started
> automatically and only once after an Ubuntu VM will be deployed from a
> managed image on Azure?

Cloud-init is the way that matches your purpose. It will execute the script when the VM is created before your first connect. And you don't need to upload the script, when you use the CLI command `az vm create` to create the VM using the parameter `--custom-data` with the value of your script, then it will upload the script for you.